# Symfony / Doctrine 2.x - Show form EntityType::class list of users - save @OneToMany - error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, formbuilder

Using Symfony 4.1, Doctrine 2.x, I have three Entities. One **Subscription** can have Many **Identities** assigned (aka User accounts). When saving which Identities belong to the currently visible Subscription on screen (via standard Symfony form), it fails.

**Identity.php**

```
class Identity implements UserInterface, \Serializable, InteractiveLoginUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     */
    public $username;
```

**Subscription.php**

```
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubscriptionIdentity", mappedBy="subscription", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    public $identities;
```

**SubscriptionIdentity.php**

```
class SubscriptionIdentity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subscription", inversedBy="identities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscription_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    public $subscription;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Identity", inversedBy="subscriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="identity_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    public $identity;
```

I have the following Form

```
class GeneralSettingsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ....<snip>....
            ->add('identities', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Who can view this subscription',
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => Identity::class,
                //'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'username',
                'multiple' => true,
```

**This works for for displaying a list box of options for the end user to select from:**

[EntityType form field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwY47.png)

When I save my form I get this issue:

```
ORMInvalidArgumentException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Expected value of type "App\Entity\**SubscriptionIdentity**" for association field
 "App\Entity\Subscription#$identities", got "App\Entity\Identity" instead.
```

Please help! Symfony / Doctrine documentation is not overly helpful in this case. Thanks.

Comment: In your GeneralSettingsType, replace this line ```'class' => Identity::class,``` by ```'class' => SubscriptionIdentity::class,```. Don't forget to import SubscriptionEntity as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you try to assign a object of type `Identity` to a attribut where doctrine waiting for un object off type `SubscriptionIdentity`.

What you describe here is a many to many relation.

Try to modify your entities like this:

```
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Identity")
     * @JoinTable(name="subscription_identity",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subscription_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="identity_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    public $identities;
```

cf: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: Will try this next week and report back - thank you.

Comment: It worked! I applied the logic in that link you pasted to all files - reversing my use of @JoinColumn("name="Changed to: Other Entity column name", "referencedColumnName="Changed to: Column name in Entity you are editing")

Comment: Symfony now also highlights the users in my list box appropriately when the form loads, whether that is one, or multiple - perfect. Now working out how to allow no selection - which seems like an unrelated issue.